# How can I fixed element a button in col-lg-8?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, fixed

I want it as I shared in the picture below but I couldn't set it up. I am sharing the code I wrote below. How can I fix this problem?

[image]

**my code:**

```css
#mybtn{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8" style="position: relative;">
        <p>this is my content</p>
        <button id="mybtn">My Fixed Button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <p>content area</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you can apply ```d-flex ml-auto``` bootstrap classes to the button to achieve what you wish to do.

Comment: Use [`position: absolute`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) with relative parent.

Comment: use position: absolute instead position:fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap `button` inside `div` and use `d-flex justify-content-end` on `div`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-8 bg-danger">
    <p>this is my content</p>
    <div class='w-100 d-flex justify-content-end'>
      <button id="mybtn" class='btn btn-primary btn-sm'>Button</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <p>content area</p>
  </div>
</div>
```